# Keyboard shortcut to show/hide Document Outline in Interface Builder

Tags: xcode, interface-builder, keyboard-shortcuts

I need to frequently hide and unhide navigators and inspectors to make room for Interface Builder and complex storyboards. I learned all show/hide shortcuts in Xcode for panes, but can't find any for showing and hiding Document Outline. Is there a way to achieve this on keyboard?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is no defined keyboard shortcut to show/hide the document outline. But you can define new shortcuts for these actions.

Just open the preferences (<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd>) and search for "Document Outline" in the "Key Bindings" page.

Comment: I am aware of these shortcuts and I am using all of them. I am looking for a specific one which is not in the View menu. You can find the command in Editor->Hide/Show Document Outline, or you can hit the little arrow in the bottom left corner of the IB. Is there a way to do this via shortcut?

Comment: I see, there is no keyboard shortcut defined for these. But you can define some in the preferences. I also update my answer.

Comment: Ok, now I understand how to do it in Preferences. I did Cmd+9 for both 'Show Document Outline' and 'Hide Document Outline' menu titles in App Shortcuts and it works like a charm. Thank you.

Comment: For such one off menu commands, it is often faster to use Cmd+Shift+? to bring up the help search, and type a fuzzy match (e.g. "outline" in this case). [Edit: [Damn!](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26207/how-can-i-format-as-keyboard-keys#comment477285_26209)]

Comment: `⌃⌘0` seems like a good key combination for those looking for something consistent with the default shortcuts for toggling the Navigator and Utilities panes (`⌘0` and `⌥⌘0` respectively)

Comment: In Xcode 11, it was renamed to `View` > `Editor` > `Show Document Items`.

Answer (score 7):

Just to demonstrate the other solution how to setup the shortcut in System Preferences->Keyboard->Shortcuts.

[image]

Comment: I couldn't enter the apple symbol ..How do I enter ?

Comment: It's the command button, or cmd. I can see Apple introduced the shortcut in Xcode 8.

Answer (score 1):

In one of the Xcode updates 6 or 7. 
⌘9 is re-allotted for Navigators > Show Reports Navigator

so, 
System Preferences > Keyboard > Shortcuts > App Shortcuts > Show/ Hide Document Outline ⌘9
is invalidated by Xcode automatically.

⇧⌘9 is what I chose. in the Keybindings.